# QWebView don't interact correctly with AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, qt, webview

I'm developing a desktop application for accessing multiple instance of the Amazon Web Services site with different accounts for which i just need a basic interaction.
For what i can understand the AWS site is written with AJAX and for just accessing the site, displaying it's content and interact with simple features like editing files, the QWebView of the QT framework is plenty.

Problems arise when the QWebView tries to interact with uploads and downloads in the S3 buckets:

- Uploads: enabling the java and javascript global webattribute i can easily upload files trough js but the "enhanced java uploader" for uploading files bigger than 300MB and multiple files is disabled and i can't figure out how to add this feature.
  [image]
- Downloads: when i select the file and the download option a link popup which i should right-click and choose "save as" for downloading it. I have already coded a simple downloader so when i click links connected to files the download starts automatically (but it works only on html only). So far no problems but the QWebView can't interact with such link (no signal emits when i try to access the object so i guess the "dialog" that pop up is not correctly mapped inside the QWebView).
  [image]

The expected behaviour should be to be able to interact with the site like any other browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered leveraging the S3 Bucket API directly?